# how to pass the array to php file?

Tags: php, html

I got the sort to work. But if I want call a php file from href, it's giving me the array is null error. How to pass the array to php file

I tried putting `usort` in the main php file before, but that too didn't work

```
<?php
function build_sorter($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}
?> //this is the sort_field code and I am trying to call it to 
<th><a href="../Model/sort_field.php">Name</a></th>

<?php usort($products, build_sorter('productName')); ?>
```

I expected the output when clicking to be sorted with brown sugar being the top result.

This is the error I am getting:

> Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Group5CISPHPProject1\Model\sort_field.php on line 11

Comment: Try passing your array to sort_field.php by using html form. Use JSON to encode your array into a string, and then decode it with sort_field.php.

Comment: @ryanc I'm pretty new at php, so how do I go along with this?

Comment: What you need is a html form to send data to your php file. [Check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form)

Comment: @ryanc if I do understand what you're saying, I think I already have a form set up. For what I'm doing, clicking on the name will sort the name, but hence giving me that error.  As for JSON I haven't learned  JavaScript yet in my class, so I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: And to make any changes in this code always has a "expects parameter 1 to be array null given" on this line with                                                              "<?php usort($products, build_sorter('productName')); ?>"

Comment: Is the contents of sort_field.php the code above? If so, try resolving the $products variable being Null.